# ubuntu gnome 14.04 can't turn off built-in display

Tags: gnome, 14.04, multiple-monitors, display

I have ubuntu 14.04 gnome(3.12) on my laptop. My laptop screen is broken so I just have an external monitor plugged in and I use that. In the passed version I would just turn off the built-in (broken) display but for some reason I can't do that now. It shows I have 3 displays (which is weird sense I only have 2, built-in and external, but I read that was a bug and it hasn't bothered me really sense it's off), it has built-in as secondary and external as primary. When I try to turn off the built-in it just goes back to secondary.

This wouldn't be a big deal if my windows would stop opening in the built-in display. Then I can't see them because that display is broken, and I can't move them. So I have to change the settings to mirror then the external back to primary then all the windows move to the external but I have to do that every time I open a new window. Getting very annoying. Anyone know a fix? I have noticed there are a few settings that won't set in the gnome-control-center and I have to set them using dconf editor so I am used to that but I don't know if there is a setting there for it or where it would be. Thank you for any help!

Comment: To change the dual display mode to the desired one, simple cycle through Fn +F5 (or whatever your key combination is) multiple times until you get the desired behaviour.

Comment: That didn't work, all I got was a bunch of messed up lines on my monitor and it wouldn't come back and I had to reboot.

Comment: Then maybe there's an issue with the compatibility of the external monitor and the video card refresh and resolution settings. You might want to create an xorg.conf file. You may end up with a system that doesn'nt boot. In that case, boot from a live DVD or USB and delete the offending xorg.conf file.

Comment: Okay, do you know of a tutorial on creating a xorg.conf file? I have read about that some but I wouldn't know what exactly to do to fix my problem.

Comment: THere seems to be another option: See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/5266/30019

Comment: I tried what that suggested with the xrandr commands and set my external to primary and I even tried to turn off the built-in display with 'xrandr --output LVDS1 --off' which seemed to do exactly the same thing as the gnome display settings. I will look up the xorg.conf file stuff and see if it will work like I want it to and update here.

Comment: You can use `Alt+F7` to move the selected window, `Alt+Tab` to select windows.

Comment: Well that's not really a fix, I would like a fix so I wouldn't have to deal with it at all but I guess that is easier than what I have been doing.